# The Remainder of Taylor Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In the Lang's Calculus bok says that

$R_n (x)=\dfrac {f^{n}\left( c\right) } {n!}(x-a)^{n}$ where $c$ is between $x$ and $a$.

But, I saw that in the a lecture note,

$R_n (x)=\dfrac {f^{n+1}\left( c\right) } {(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$ where $c$ is between $x$ and $a$.

**Which is the true?** So, for an example, $f(x)=e^x$. The remainder ,as the lecture note, is $R_4=\left| \dfrac {e^{c}} {120}\left( x-1\right) ^{5}\right|
$ but as Lang's the book formula, $R_4=\left| \dfrac {e^{c}} {24}\left( x-1\right) ^{4}\right|$.

Comment: Can you say that what is the remainder formula as this (link): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorsTheorem.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Langrange's form of remainder goes as follows:

> Let $f$ posess atleast $n+1$ derivatives over an open interval $I$ and
>   let  $c\in I$.
>
> Let  $$P_n(x)=\sum_0^n\dfrac{f^{(i)}(c)(x-c)^i}{i!}$$ and let
>   $$R_n(x)=f(x)-P_n(x)$$ Then for each $x\in I$ there exists $z$ between
>   $x$ and $c$ such that 
>   $$R_n(x)=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(z)(x-c)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}$$

In your example, $e^x$ is infinitely differentiable over $R$. So, for a the Taylor polynomial of degree $4$, the remainder should be of the second form you mentioned.